# Make device accessible outside firewall with OpenVPN

Tags: networking, openvpn, forwarding

I have an OpenVPN server and a few clients already configured. The server allocates IP addresses in the 10.9.9.1-254 range. One of these clients, "J", is allocated 10.9.9.24 on the VPN and 10.0.27.9 on its own LAN. It's on the same local network as a device that I would like to make accessible through the VPN, but the device is not capable of running an OpenVPN client. I can access the device directly from J at the address 10.0.27.4, assigned by J's network.

I followed the directions [here](http://www.secure-computing.net/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN/Routing) on the VPN server, but I'm not sure what to do on J to configure it to forward traffic between the device and the VPN. Forwarding the entire LAN would be optimal, but access to the single device is all that I need at the moment. Unfortunately, I have no control over the router between J and the device.

J runs Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tell the VPN server that it can reach the LAN subnet through OpenVPN. Add the following to the OpenVPN server configuration:

   ```
   route 10.0.27.0 255.255.255.0
   ```
2. Tell the OpenVPN server which client has access to this subnet. You need the client-config-dir feature here, so add this to the OpenVPN server configuration if you don't already have it:

   ```
   client-config-dir clients
   ```

   and then create a configuration file for the client on the server (e.g. `/etc/openvpn/clients/J`, where "J" is the common name on the client's certificate):

   ```
   iroute 10.0.27.0 255.255.255.0
   ```
3. Then you need to ensure that the return traffic from the LAN device back to the VPN server goes via J. This can be done by making J the default gateway for the device, or adding a route like this on the device or the LAN default gateway:

   ```
   ip route add 10.9.9.0/24 via 10.0.27.9
   ```
4. If you want other machines on the VPN server's network to be able to access the device you also need to make them aware of the LAN subnet. Again this can be done by making the VPN server the default gateway of the other machines, or adding a route like this to the other machines or the default gateway (where 10.0.8.10 is the LAN IP of the VPN server):

   ```
   ip route add 10.0.27.0/24 via 10.0.8.10
   ```

Comment: I completed steps 1 and 2 as part of the page I linked. I've updated my post to reflect that J runs Windows 7. My plan is to make J the default gateway for the device. Is there an equivalent Windows command to add the route in step 3? Do I need to do anything to enable traffic forwarding?

Comment: @AndreBoos I don't know how to setup forwarding on Windows.